# Why does sometimes some of cards doesn't rotate at all?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEoONW

Cards at least heave minimum 180 degree rotation, set in CSS with JS, but in multiple run some of it doesn't rotate at all. Can anyone please explain why?

```
<div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
        <div class="front"></div>
        <div class="back">?</div>
    </div>
</div>
...

<button onclick="rotate();">Rotate</button>
<style>
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000px;float:left;
}
.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 160px;height: 220px;
}
.flipper {
    transform-style:preserve-3d;position: relative;
}
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;    
}
.front {
    z-index: 2; transform: rotateY(0deg);background-color: blue;
}
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg); background-color: grey;font-size: 13em; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
<script>
function rnd(){
    var randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
    if(randNum %2 == 0){//generated number is even
       randNum  = randNum +1 ;       
    }
    return randNum;
}
function rotate(){
    $('.flipper').each(function(i, obj) {
        var rn = rnd();
        var nn = 180 * rn;
        var sp = 0.2 * rn;
        console.log(rn);
        $(this).css("transition", sp+"s").css("transform", "rotateY("+nn+"deg)");
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: maybe has something to do with it being random

Comment: I found out that when the same card gets the exact random number as before, it will not rotate.

Comment: That was going to be my suggestion, Aziz

Comment: So the solution will be reset cards position to initial before every rotate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy.

To start rotating in this pen, card has to receive *new* css.

If the number, that was generated by rnd() function is the same as previous one, css of the element is not changed, so browser doesnt start the animation, it thinks that's it already been played (and it was).

To 'restart animation' if it has SAME params you have two ways - or remove element from DOM and get it back there (ugly, ah?) OR you can clear style and then set it back in time out. That trick will help 'restart' animation.

```
$element.attr('style', null); //remove old style before setting new
setTimeout(function(){

   $element.css("transition", "0.6s");
   $element.css("transform", "rotateY("180deg)");
}, 100);
```

I've forked you pen and made all cards spin [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JKzEJK).

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extra checker to prevent the same card from recieing the exact number as before:

```
function rotate() {
  $('.flipper').each(function(i, obj) {
    var rn = rnd();
    if ( $(this).data('rn') == rn ) { rn = rn + 2; }
    var nn = 180 * rn;
    var sp = 0.2 * rn;
    $(this).data('rn', rn);
    $(this).css("transition", sp + "s");
    $(this).css("transform", "rotateY(" + nn + "deg)");
    console.log(i + ': ' + rn + ' -d: ' + $(this).data('rn'));
  });
}
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
function rnd() {
  var randNum = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 1);
  if (randNum % 2 == 0) { randNum = randNum + 1; }
  return randNum;
}

function rotate() {
  $('.flipper').each(function(i, obj) {
    var rn = rnd();
    if ( $(this).data('rn') == rn ) { rn = rn + 2; }
    var nn = 180 * rn;
    var sp = 0.2 * rn;
    $(this).data('rn', rn);
    $(this).css("transition", sp + "s");
    $(this).css("transform", "rotateY(" + nn + "deg)");
    //console.log(i + ': ' + rn + ' -d: ' + $(this).data('rn'));
  });
}
rotate();

$('body').on('click', '#rotate', function(){rotate();});
```

```css
.cards::after { clear:both; content: ''; display: table;}

/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
  perspective: 1000px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
}

.flip-container,.front,.back {
  width: 160px;
  height: 220px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
  transition: 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}


/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
  z-index: 2;
  /* for firefox 31 */
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
  background-color: blue;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background-color: grey;
  font-size: 13em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cards">
  <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <!-- front content -->
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        ?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <!-- front content -->
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        ?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <!-- front content -->
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        ?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <!-- front content -->
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        ?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <!-- front content -->
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        ?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flip-container">
    <div class="flipper">
      <div class="front">
        <!-- front content -->
      </div>
      <div class="back">
        ?
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button id="rotate">Rotate</button>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/9v6340fd/